# SQL trigger to check if row already exists

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

So I have two tables(orders and fabric_order). This sql is triggered after an insert is done on another table. I don't want duplicate rows, so I wanna check the table (fabric_orders) if already has a row with a code equal to the code from the other table (orders) and insert into table (fabric_order) only if doesn't exist the same code

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    select code 
    from orders
    WHERE code=fabric_order.code
)
INSERT INTO fabric_order (order_id, code, start_date)
SELECT(id, code, deliver_date)
FROM orders
```

[image: Tables]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have a trigger for it a `INSERT ... SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ..` should also have the same results.

```
INSERT INTO fabric_order AS fabric_order_outer (
     fabric_order_outer.order_id
   , fabric_order_outer.code
   , fabric_order_outer.start_date
)
SELECT(
     orders.id
   , orders.code
   , orders.deliver_date
)
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN 
  fabric_order AS fabric_order_inner
ON
 orders.code = fabric_order_inner.code
WHERE
 fabric_order_inner.order_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This gives the following error `Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous ) `, probably because i have a column in the table (fabric_order and orders) with the name `id`

Comment: @LuisLuisMaiaMaia one time I deviate from mine personal rule to using fully quantified or aliases in SQL annywhere there is trouble